# Counting no of ways under overlapping cases.

Tags: combinatorics

I have infinte supply of red and black balls and i am asked what will be  the count of number of different arrangements having occurrences of RR, RB, BB and BR equal to inputs A,B,C, and D, respectively can be made ?
For ex if A = 1,B = 1,C = 2,D = 1
Then there are 5 possible arrangements
RRBBBR
RBBBRR
BRRBBB
BBRRBB
BBBRRB
Note that in all above arrangements RR occurs A = 1 no of times,RB occurs B = 1 no of times and say on...

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632347/number-of-binary-numbers-given-constraints-on-consecutive-elements)